# Function Plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I m new to Matlab and I need it for my senior seminar project.
How would I plot a function of the form
$x_{i+1}=f(x_i), \;f(x)=rx(1-x)$, for x=linspace(0,1) and some $\;r$?
I m supposed to plot x as a function of time.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `help plot`?

Comment: i think you just showed me my whole project

Answer (score 0):

The `plot` function is what you are looking for, as described by [AnonSubmitter85](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33383) in the comments.

Details for this command can be found by typing `help plot` (or `doc plot` in the GUI version) at the terminal to display help for the command.